# Add Ajax modal popup to another button

Tags: ajax, shopify

https://bpt9hyq9jz7t6wkd-26803830855.shopifypreview.com
On homepage, if you click on the cart button it'll show a popup of the cart, with what product was added, how many products are in the cart, etc. if you instead go here: https://bpt9hyq9jz7t6wkd-26803830855.shopifypreview.com/collections/all 
 due to the fact that it is created with an app to improve filters, the button (both normal and quick view) is not connected to the modal popup. I've tried to figure it out, but while I can sorta understand Html and CSS, Ajax is new to me. I figured that this is the Ajax that calls upon the modal box? Any help would be appreciated:

```js
        initAddToCart: function() {
            if (e(".add-cart-btn").length > 0) {
                e(".add-cart-btn").click(function(n) {
                    n.preventDefault();
                    if (e(this).attr("disabled") != "disabled") {
                        var r = e(this).parents(".item-row");
                        var i = e(r).attr("id");
                        i = i.match(/\d+/g);
                        if (!window.ajax_cart) {
                            e("#cart-form-" + i).submit()
                        } else {
                            var s = e("#cart-form-" + i + " select[name=id]").val();                          
                            if (!s) {
                                s = e("#cart-form-" + i + " input[name=id]").val()
                            }                          
                            var o = e("#cart-form-" + i + " select[name=quantity]").val();
                            if (!o) {
                                o = 1
                            }
                          console.log(o);
                           var a = e(r).find(".featured-image").attr("src");
                           var p = e(r).find(".grid-link__title").text();
                           var amt = e(r).find(".grid-link__meta .product_price .grid-link__org_price span.money").text();                         
                            t.doAjaxAddToCart(s, o, a, p, amt)
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                })
            }
        },
        showLoading: function() {
            e(".loading-modal").show()
        },
        hideLoading: function() {
            e(".loading-modal").hide()
        },
        doAjaxAddToCart: function(n, r, a, p, amt) {
            e.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/cart/add.js",
                data: "quantity=" + r + "&id=" + n,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    t.showLoading()
                },
                success: function(n) {
                    t.hideLoading();                    
                    t.showModal(".ajax-success-modal");
                     e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".ajax-product-image").attr("src", a);
                     e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".added-to-wishlist").hide();
                     e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".added-to-cart").show();
                     e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".ajax-product-title").text(p);
                     e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".ajax_price").text(amt);
                    e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".ajax_qty").text(r);
                  e.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: '/cart.js',
   success: function(cart){
      e(".ajax-success-modal").find(".ajax_qtyA").text(cart.item_count);
   }
});
```

Comment: okay, so as per my understanding you want to add the AJAX cart to APP loaded quick view and add to cart button, right?

Comment: AJAX popup, yes.

Comment: You need to edit the JS code to add the AJAX code, it will need more skill because it needs much code editing into `shop.js`

Comment: So its not just a matter of connecting the button to the currently available popup?

Comment: No, actually structure of the HTML is not the same added by APP so the default theme code does not work in this case. You need to check it APP settings might be any options to own AJAX cart functionality?

Comment: unfortunately yes, the app uses another html, and it does not have any options of its own to connect to ajax. The whole collection section is different from the standard one from template.